# How to load a column generated by awk into a python list

Tags: python, list, awk

With awk it is very easy to extract a column of data in the bash terminal using.

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

I am doing this inside a python script where i use a bash sequence to extract the data i'm interested in

```
os.system(" qstat | awk '{print $1}' ")
```

If i call this in a certain context I get a column of numbers.  I would like to load all of those numbers into a python list.   Can this be done easily?

Comment: Why are you using `awk`? Why not do it all in Python? It's just `[line.partition(" ")[0] for line in fileinput.input()]`.

Comment: Please see the edit to the OP.  I am doing this inside a python script already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `subprocess` instead of `os.system()`:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('ls | awk "{print $1}"', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]
for item in stdout_value.split('\n'):
    print item
```

Comment: If you are going to use `communicate` you might as well use `subprocess.check_output`

Comment: What advantage do you get by using check_output?

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output of awk to your Python script.

```
$ awk '{print $1}' input.txt | python script.py
```

To read from the pipe in Python use sys.stdin:

```
import sys
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Comment: please see the edit i made to OP.  I am doing this inside a python script already.

Comment: Ahhh. Your question makes a lot more sense now. I couldn't see the update for some reason.